# View source code with login (PHP)

Tags: php, file, google-chrome, authentication, xampp

I am trying to view the source code of a website which needs Google login.

I am logged into my Google account on Chrome, and I am running the php file on Chrome using XAMPP.

My code:

`<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    echo $homepage;
?>`

However, when I echo it shows me a webpage that says I am not logged in, although I am logged in. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I understand it is because I don't have the cookies when I run it using XAMPP. How do I run it on Chrome so that it will use Chrome's cookies?

Comment: the php file doesn't run in chrome, it runs in apache or whichever web server you are running. Long story short, when the web server tries to fetch the url it does not have the cookie(s) you have for that site in Chrome, hence it is unauthenticated.

Comment: How do I run the php file in Chrome in a way that it will use the cookies?

Comment: It would be a huge security problem if website A could read the cookies of website B. It would allow any malicious site to read your Facebook/Google/etc session IDs, which we don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to log in with your PHP-Server before you can fetch the loggedin-website.
This is achievable by using CURL with active cookiefiles.

(You have to do all the login-process within your PHP!!)

Well you start your CURL-Action with some parameters which could look quite different depending on the website-specific login process.
See this image for an example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwX4x.png (very old example of some login)